# Как задать диапазон чисел в рандоме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Всем привет! Я хочу задать диапазон чисел допустим для рандома? Как это сделать?
Вот например, у меня есть код:

```
from random import randint
ques_one = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
ques_two = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
print(randint(ques_one, ques_two))
```

Вопрос: как я могу сделать так, чтобы это убралось в две или три строчки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint
ques_one, ques_two = [int(i) for i in input('Введите Два числа через пробел: ').split(" ")]
print(randint(ques_one, ques_two))

Введите Два числа через пробел: >? 1 10
5
```

Если значения диапазонов не будут нигде использоваться, то можно сделать так:

```
from random import randint
print(randint(*[int(i) for i in input('Введите Два числа через пробел: ').split(" ")]))

Введите Два числа через пробел: >? 1 10
9
```